# Keep a section fixed to browser window

Tags: html, css

I am trying to keep a div fixed to the browser window when scrolling through content but I just can't seem to get it to work.

Here is what I have going on so far:

**HTML**

```
<section id="adminpanel">
        <!--Drop down-->
        <!--Button-->
        <!--Drop down-->
        <!--Button-->
        <!--Drop down-->
        <!--Button-->
</section>
<!--This is the content section-->
<div class="content">
    <div id="accounts">
        <!--content-->
    </div>
    <div id="facilities">
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
    </div>
</div>
<footer>
    <p>Copyright &copy</p>
</footer>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color:grey;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

#adminpanel {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    height:100%;
    width:15%;
    float:left;
}
.content {
    position: relative;
    width:85%;
    min-height: 100%;
    float:left;
    background-color:silver;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
footer {
    text-align:center;
    position: fixed;
    padding:5px;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
    background: #999999;
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/or9vkxuu/) demonstrating where I'm at so far.

I have tried setting `position: fixed;` on the `#adminpanel` but that just seems to mess everything else up, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean it seems to mess things up? You want it to be where it was on the left but never move?

Comment: It looks like it works for me. I am guessing that the 'messed up' part is that the rest of your content shifts around whenever you apply `position: fixed` to `#adminpanel`? Also, you'll need to apply a z-index greater than the `.content` element to get `#adminpanel` to show up. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/fxvexogc/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/or9vkxuu/1/

```
#adminpanel {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    height:100%;
    width:15%;
    float:left;
    position:fixed;
}
.content {
    position: relative;
    width:85%;
    min-height: 100%;
    float:left;
    background-color:silver;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    margin-left: 15%;
}
```

If you put position fixed on that element, you need to add margin-left with the same width in the content element, because #adminpanel is no stacked anymore.

Comment: Ah, ok thats what I was missing - setting margin-left to the same width. Thanks this is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

In some browsers you have to assign a `display: block` to the html5 semantic elements like `article, nav, footer, section, etc..`.

So with `display: block` and `position: fixed` it works perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/or9vkxuu/2/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
        }

        #adminpanel {
            line-height: 30px;
            background-color: #eeeeee;
            height: 100%;
            width: 15%;
            float: left;
        }

        .content {
            width: 85%;
            min-height: 100%;
            float: left;
            background-color: silver;
            margin-bottom: 60px;
        }

        footer {
            text-align: center;
            position: fixed;
            padding: 5px;
            left: 0px;
            bottom: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            background: #999999;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<section id="adminpanel">
    <p> Left Admin panal</p>
    <!--Drop down-->
    <!--Button-->
    <!--Drop down-->
    <!--Button-->
    <!--Drop down-->
    <!--Button-->
</section>
<!--This is the content section-->
<div class="content">
    <div id="accounts">
        <!--content-->
    </div>
    <div id="facilities">
        <p>test</p>

        <p>test</p>

        <p>test</p>

        <p>test</p>

        <p>test</p>

        <p>test</p>

        <p>test</p>

        <p>test</p>

        <p>test</p>

        <p>test</p>

        <p>test</p>

        <p>test</p>

        <p>test</p>

        <p>test</p>

        <p>test</p>

        <p>test</p>

        <p>test</p>

        <p>test</p>

        <p>test</p>

        <p>test</p>

        <p>test</p>

        <p>test</p>

        <p>test</p>

        <p>test</p>
    </div>
</div>
<footer>
    <p>Copyright &copy</p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```